# How to distinguish a bool from a z3 expression?

Tags: python, python-2.7, z3, z3py

I read z3 expressions from an input file in Python. Then later in my code I call `__deepcopy__()` on them.

The problem is that sometimes the input z3 expression is `True` or `False`, then Python gets confused and thinks they are bool and refuses to call `__deepcopy__()`. 
The error message is

`AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__deepcopy__'`

How can I distinguish between bool and z3 expressions in this case?

Comment: Please post an MCVE. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an explicit test whether your expression is a Z3 expression, using `isinstance(e, ExprRef)`. Note the difference between `False` as a Python boolean (`b > 7`) and a Z3 boolean (`simplify(And(a > 7, b > 7))`).

```py
from z3 import Int, simplify, And, ExprRef

a = Int('a')
b = 3
expr = [a + 3,
        a < 7,
        And(a < 7, a > 2),
        And(a < 7, b > 7),
        simplify(And(a > 7, b > 7)),
        b > 7,
        True]

expr_copy = [e.__deepcopy__() if isinstance(e, ExprRef) else e for e in expr]
print(expr_copy)
for e in expr:
    print(f'Is "{e}" a Z3 expression? {isinstance(e, ExprRef)}')
```

Output:

```
[a + 3, a < 7, And(a < 7, a > 2), And(a < 7, False), False, False, True]
Is "a + 3" a Z3 expression? True
Is "a < 7" a Z3 expression? True
Is "And(a < 7, a > 2)" a Z3 expression? True
Is "And(a < 7, False)" a Z3 expression? True
Is "False" a Z3 expression? True
Is "False" a Z3 expression? False
Is "True" a Z3 expression? False
```